# Using a button to open a form in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Okay I've added a form to my project named it Checkout.

With a button on the original form I should type

```
Checkout myNewForm = new Checkout();
myNewForm.Show();
```

Visual studio does not recognize Checkout so I cannot create a new one in the original form, what is happening, everywhere else on the web including a video tutorial says this should work.

Comment: Do you have `Checkout` class defined somewhere and if yes, have you added `using` namespace correctly?

Comment: That was the problem, I'd renamed the namespace in the project weeks ago, and somehow the two have different namespaces. Changed that and now its working!